# Is Microsoft Bot Framework Composer compatible with Dot Net 6.0 or Dot Net 7.0 SDK Installations?

Tags: azure, bots, botframework, .net-sdk

I have installed Dot Net 6.0 & 7.0 SDK versions in my computer. I have also installed Bot Framework Composer 2.1.2. I just created an empty bot and started it for testing. But the build is always failing.
Error Message: You must install or update .NET to run this application.

I know that Dot Net 3.1 version has reached it end of life and support will no longer be provided for it. Should I still download it to make the composer work or is there a way to work with 7.0 or 6.0 versions of Dot Net SDK?

Answer (score 3):

I have installed the .NET 6 and have done the following steps to start the Bot in the Bot Framework Composer:

1. Close the Bot Framework Composer
2. Navigate to the directory of my bot created in the composer and open the *bot-name*.csproj with an editor
3. Change the `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>`
   to `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`
4. Save the change
5. Restart  the Bot Framework Composer and start the bot